# Assigning through random generated indexes

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to write a function that assign N elements to M players. Here's what I wrote:

```
void assignElements(Player *p, Tab *t, int n) {
    int i = 0, nRand, flagElements = 0;
    do {
        do {
            nRand = MINRANDT + rand() % (MAXRANDT - MINRANDT + 1);
        } while(t[nRand].type != Terrain && t[nRand].idProp != -1); 

        if (i == n) {
            i = 0;  //this makes "i" reset when it reaches the number of players
        }
        t[nRand].idProp = i;
        p[i].numTerrains++;
        i++;
        flagElements++;

    } while (flagElements != NELEMENTS);
}
```

So, if I try to run this function, it's not respecting the condition of the second `while` (maybe the problem is the condition.): in fact, it also assign to `t` elements that are not of type `Terrain` (this is an `enum`). The condition to do the actions under the `nRand` `do / while`, is that `nRand` have to be an index of a `t` element that is of type `Terrain`, and that its `idProp` is `-1` (this mean it has not been assigned yet). Hope anyone can help. :)

Comment: *assign N elements to M players, equally* - What do you mean by equally

Comment: @EdHeal   For example: 24 elements, 5 players: 1st Player: 5 elements, 2nd: 5, 3rd: 5, 4th: 5, 5th, 4. Actually it's doing it fine. But the problem is that it assigns some 't' elements that aren't of the desired type.

Comment: So you do not mind players losing out (i.e. 5 != 4 for the 4th and 5th players)

Comment: @EdHeal no, it have to be like I said.

Comment: Forgive me but 5 elements is not **equal** to 4 elements

Comment: @EdHeal ok, let's change it then, It's not equal, but it have to do it as i said. But that's not the  actual problem

Comment: Note that your random selection may run into an infinite loop if the number of terrain items is less than `NELEMENTS`. A solution where you filter out the terrain items first might be better.

Comment: @MOehm terrain items (NELEMENTS) is always the same (it's a litteral const). Do you think it's still a problem? I might solve it.

Comment: No, if you can always find a valid element you're fine. But it will take many picks to find the last remaining element, because you don't really remove the picked elements from the array. It's a problem to be aware of, but if `NELEMENTS` is small, I woudn't worry about that right now.

Comment: NELEMENTS is 24, you think it's fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t[nRand].type != Terrain | t[nRand].idProp != -1 | &&
-------------------------+-----------------------+---
          0              |          0            |  0
          0              |          1            |  0
          1              |          0            |  0
          1              |          1            |  1
```

Meaning that the loop will exit for 3 conditions and repeat only when both sub-conditions are met

Try `||`

```
t[nRand].type != Terrain | t[nRand].idProp != -1 | ||
-------------------------+-----------------------+---
          0              |          0            |  0
          0              |          1            |  1
          1              |          0            |  1
          1              |          1            |  1
```

Comment: so what would be the right way to do what I want to? I mean generating a random index that both respect these conditions.

Comment: Edited the answer with a `||` (or) table.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get why I should use the 'or' condition. Because actually, both conditions have to be verified. I mean, the do-while is intended to generate a random number until the 'nRand' is index of a 't' element, which type is 'Terrain' and at same time have 'idProp' = -1.

Comment: @THZ: Remember [de Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws): You want to get `type == Terrain && isProp == -1`, so you have to loop while that condition is false. The negation of the condition is `type != Terrain || isProp != -1`. (You should probably also be aware of infinite re-rolling loops.)

Comment: I think it solved my problem. I will do more tests but it's working for now. Sorry but while condition have always been a problem for me ^^